# Domain Object that needs more than one Data Mapper

Tags: php, oop, data-modeling, repository-pattern

I'm trying to figure out how to reuse Domain Models in different parts of the application and I have a feeling that the Data Mapper pattern is the way forward. The example below has methods that directly access the methods of the Mapper.

```
class Groups
{
    protected $_groups = array();

    public function addGroup($name)
    {
        $this->_groups[] = $name;
    }

    public function doSomethingGroupy($cakes)
    {
        // get all the groups that have cake
        return $cakeyGroups;
    }
}
```

... And a mapper to match the methods on the Groups class.

```
class GroupMapper
{
    public function find($id, Groups $group)
    {
         // Mappy type things, maybe some sql
    }

    public function fetchByNeediness($cuddles, Groups $group)
    {
         // More mappy type things
    }

    public function save(Groups $groups)
    {
         //  Saves
    }
}
```

However if sometime later I wanted to use the same Groups Models but populate the groups using different queries I would use a different mapper.

```
class AngryGroupMapper
{
    public function find($id, Groups $group)
    {
        // Something similar but with other tables and joins
    }

    public function fetchByRage($anger, Groups $group)
    {
        // Something new but only needed here
    }

    public function isEditable(Groups $groups)
    {
         // Do some querying
         return $bool;
    {
}
```

Now I Know the aim is Skinny Controller - Fat Model, so would I have another model to Map the Mapper (so to speak) to the Model?

```
class FatModelRepository
{
    public function getHappyGroups()
    {
        $mapper = new GroupMapper();
        return $mapper->fetchByNeediness('Puffy Shoes', new Groups());
    }

    public function getSadGroups()
    {
        $mapper = new AngryGroupMapper();
        return $mapper->fetchByRage('Aghh!', new Groups());
    {

    public function save(Groups $groups)
    {
        $mapper = new GroupMapper();
        return $mapper->save($groups);
    {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Data Model should have no knowledge of the Data Mapper. Your Groups class/model shouldn't have find methods and it should not have access to the mapper.

Once you remove the mapper dependency from your model your problems will go away.

NOTE: check out [Doctrine 2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/introduction/en#introduction)

Comment: What if "Groups" is a collection containing "Group" objects and those are models themselves that require dependent mapping. Would you have to detach them from Groups, pass them through a Mapper and then reattach them to the collection? Would that mean the Client/Controller needs knowledge of the Mappers?

Comment: Your `FatModel` is called a Repository. There's a good explanation of it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx#id0400058

Comment: Why would you? Design it to suit your needs. I wouldn't use a repo as a cache. Put the cache on the data mapper.

Comment: Ah okay, then I'm not sure what the Unit Of Work is used for?

Comment: Repositories retrieve objects and pass them to whoever the caller was then the repository is done.  A repository does not keep track of what it retrieves itself and knows nothing at all about what other repositories may have done, or new objects that did not come from a repository at all.  To update your database someone has to know what is what?  Unit Of Work is a manager object that keeps track of everything that was retrieved from all repositories, has had records added to it for any new objects that were created and knows how to save it all in transactions.   It is a persistence session.

Comment: I've come across a Proxy for Lazy Loading dependent Domain Models.  Would the Proxy need knowledge of a Mapper of a Repository? I'm assuming that it could only have knowledge of the repository that created it's Parent Domain object. In which case a Repository would need to know how to create a complete Domain Object ie a User with composite Groups, Address objects

Comment: @gawpertron - I'm not sure what you mean? If you use Doctrine you get the proxy for free and it just works transparently in the background. I recommend getting started with Doctrine.

Comment: As far as I can see Proxies in Doctrine 2 have no methods to implement in the interface. Doctrine 2 isn't going to be possible with our current setup. The article http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns/practical-php-patterns-lazy explains how the Proxies are used in Doctrine 2. I'm looking to understand the patterns involved rather than specific implementations.

Answer (score 0):

As rojoca says you shouldnt have the fetch/find methods directly on the model. Technically hes also right about the model not storing a reference to the mapper, but in less complex situations i think this is ok so long as the model only excpets the most abstract form of mapper you plan on having (ie. some kind of base mapper class or an interface).

Given thos to things, you should only need to add methods to the mapper, and for this i would just use inheritance, ie. extend your groups mapper for the new functionality. Of course this requires that the mapper is injectable into the model. But if youre going to have the model hold a reference to its mapper then it does need to be injectable anyhow.

Comment: On my first attempts I did add a reference to the mapper, and realised early on the limitations of do this. However I can't quite picture how to use mappers without a Model or a Controller somewhere being aware of them?

Comment: i dodnt think there is anything wrong with your controllers using the mappers directly as the controllers are application/module specific.

Comment: Could a Mapper have knowledge of another Mapper?